# How to use more than one POST request in same route

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I currently have two buttons within my EJS template that have POST request methods and I can't get them both to work as I have only up until now used one POST request per route.

I have two sets of to do lists, one under the home route "/" which is identified by its key pair value list: day, and the other identified as list: "Work".

Within each list I have a post request that adds a new item and the second POST request will essentially redirect to the other to do list. These are both generated from submit buttons.

I am trying to solve this by creating a 3rd route assigned to the redirect button that redirects either to the home or work list depending on the current titleList value.

However, I can redirect from the home list to the work list, but once there I can not redirect back to the home page!

The console shows a 302 status code the moment I click the button to redirect me a second time.

I do not think at this point the get request is possible as it would be redirecting to nothing, but I do not know how to proceed further.

I am new to Node.js and Express.

My code:

***HTML***

```html
<%- include("header") -%>    
<div class="box" id="heading">
<h1><%=listTitle%></h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
<% for (let i =0; i< newListItems.length; i++) { %>
<div class="item">
<input type="checkbox">
<p><%= newListItems[i] %></p>
</div>
<% }; %>

<form class="item" action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New item?" autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit" name="list" value=<%= listTitle %>>+</button>
</form>

</div>

<form class="" action="/divert" method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn1" name="redirect" value="identify" style="width: 
100px"><%=btnName%></button>
</form> 

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

***app.js***

```js
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// globals.
let items = [];
let workItems = [];
let btnIdentify = "Work";

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//Send static css file to browser.
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
const date = new Date();
const options = {
weekday: "long",
day: "numeric",
month: "long"
};

let day = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
res.render('list', {listTitle: day, newListItems: items, btnName: btnIdentify});
});


app.post("/", function(req, res) {
let item = req.body.newItem;

if (req.body.list === "Work")  { //only uses frist word off the listTitle value.
workItems.push(item);
res.redirect("/work");
} else {
items.push(item);
res.redirect("/");
}
console.log(req.body);
})

app.get("/work", function(req,res) {

res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work list", newListItems: workItems, btnName: btnIdentify });
});

app.post("/divert", function(req,res) {
if (req.body.list !== "Work") {
res.redirect("/work");
btnIdentify = "Work";
} else if (req.body.list === "Work") {
res.redirect("/");
btnIdentify = "Home";
}
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Server is running on port 3000")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the editing advice, i will not make these mistakes next time.

Comment: You can not put two post requests in one route but you can use the **PUT** request instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, after posting the problem on here it got me thinking harder.

I inserted a EJS marker into the redirect buttons like below:

```html
<form  action=<%= resType %> method="post">
```

resType was added on server side as a new key value pair to render in both app.get routes like below:

```js
res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work list", newListItems: workItems, btnName: btnIdentify, resType: "/work" });
```

***and***

```js
res.render('list', {listTitle: day, newListItems: items, btnName: btnIdentify, resType: "/divert"});
```

So every time the redirect button was clicked it would send a POST request to the route depending on the value of resType.

All I needed to do then was write up two app.posts to receive these post requests like below:

```js
app.post("/work", function(req,res) {

    res.redirect("/");
    btnIdentify = "Work";

})

app.post("/divert", function(request,responce) {
  if (request.body.list !== "Work") {
    responce.redirect("/work");
    btnIdentify = "Home";
  }
})
```